# Windows Authentication KRB5KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED

Tags: authentication, iis-7.5, kerberos, spn

Let me preface by saying, I've been on this issue for about a week and a half now and I can't figure it out.  I think I'm close, but every time I've thought that so far, I was wrong. I've looked at every forum post I can think to search for and nothing has worked.

I am simply trying to make my web application and its respective service use windows authentication so that, in code, I can pull the currently logged in user's credentials, without prompting them, and pass them to my database stored procedure via my service.

Sounds easy enough, right?

WRONG!

With ***WireShark*** running, I keep getting a response of ***KRB_ERROR (30)*** with further details of:

***error_code: KRB5KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED (41)***

[I'll be trying this tomorrow](http://www.adopenstatic.com/cs/blogs/ken/archive/2008/02/12/16189.aspx), but I thought I'd post now in case someone has an idea as to why I keep getting the ***KRB5KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED*** error based on my current setup that I'll list below.

---

Here's my current setup:

***Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1 64-bit 4.00 GB RAM***.

For the sake of this post, we'll call this server ***DALDEP01.TEST.LOCAL***, and on it I have the following:

- ***MS SQL Server 2008 R2*** which has a database we'll call ***Deploy***.

  1. Only one user account has access to the ***Deploy*** db which is ***TEST\DeploySvc***.
  2. This user account is a ***datareader*** / ***datawriter*** and has been granted ***EXEC***.
- ***IIS 7.5*** which hosts 2 web sites:

  1. ***Deploy.Service*** that makes CRUD operations against the ***Deploy*** db.
  2. ***Deploy.Web*** that hosts a ***Silverlight 4*** application which makes calls to the ***Deploy.Service***.
  3. Both sites are configured identically *(because I'm not sure how else to do it)*:

     - They use ***DeployAppPool*** which runs under custom user account ***TEST\DeploySvc***.
     - Anonymous Authentication is ***Disabled***.
     - Windows Authentication is ***Enabled***

       1. Extended Protection is ***Accept***.
       2. Enable Kernel-mode authentication is ***Checked***.
       3. Providers are just ***Negotiate***, *as I removed NTLM because I only want Kerberos*.
- ***SPNs*** are configured as follows:

C:\> ***setspn -l deploysvc***

*Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=DeploySvc,OU=Services Accounts,DC=test,DC=local:

                  HTTP/deploy.test.local

                  HTTP/deploy*

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for a duplicate SPN to cause this issue...

```
setspn -X
```

...will show you if there are any duplicates in your domain and you will need to remove the offending one. Or you could use the [SPN Query Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee176972.aspx). I'm also assuming you've already modified the delegation tab in AD for the service account so it's trusted for delegation?

Comment: There are no duplicates. As for as delegation and trust goes, am I supposed to trust the user account the application pool runs under or am I supposed to trust the user accounts that will be accessing the website or both or neither?

Comment: The service account running the application pool should be the one where delegation is allowed. Also, after rereading your original question, it occurred to me that you'll need SPNs set on the database server or whichever service account is running SQL there. Or have you done that already?

Comment: The application pool account is what has access to SQL

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue.

It turned out to be SPN related. The SPN had been mapped to the machine account of the SQL Server instead of mapped to the service account that was running SQL Server.

We deleted and recreated the SPN - mapped to the service account running SQL Server 2012R2 on the host and everything was gravy.